# Issues while Unit testing in c#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have a class Library project which will be consumed by some legacy code and some modernized code. briefly I would like to show what issues I am facing with.

```
class ClasslibraryService
{
    private Dependency1 _dependency1;
    private Dependency2 _dependency2
    public  ClasslibraryService(Dependency1 dependency)
    {
        _dependency1 = dependency;
         // this dependency2 could be something like logger or Bearer token service which I do not want to expose to consuming application
        _dependency2 = new Dependency2(new Dependency3());
    }
    public int DoSomeOperation()
    {
        var res = _dependency2.DoSomething();
        return _dependency1.DoSomeOperation(res);
    }
}
```

So basically I had to new up within constructor without injecting dependency using constructor.

Now while unit test this class , I have created another constructor which takes all dependency through constructor. This is working fine.

But question here is

1. I know I am violating main objective of unit testing by creating another constructor.Actual code will not be using this constructor. But I could not find any other way too!!
2. If 1 is not correct solution , please suggest me one solution

TIA

Comment: You can't mock dependencies created within the class with `new`. In its current form, **you have to test the whole thing** in a single go, including dependencies, as they can't be mocked. For a proper test, inject everything though constructor, remove the `new` and inject mocks for testing.

Comment: But I cant do that . Because I would need dependency2.DoSomething(); to be mocked setup for testing DoSomeOperation() . its a bunch of api calls within dependency2.DoSomething(). So I need to mock that . Thats why I had to write another constructor and inject it just for Unit test . I would like to know if this approach is Ok or not

Comment: I agree, it would be terribly difficult to do so. Your first solution is the right way, add all dependencies to the constructor and remove the `new`s all over the place, just like it's done with `Dependency1`. You can then mock everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know I am violating main objective of unit testing by creating
> another constructor.Actual code will not be using this constructor.
> But I could not find any other way too!!

I know this is heresy for some but I believe there's no hard rule in software development. It's a game of tradeoffs. If it's too expensive to change how your constructor works, you can probably do something like this for now:

```
public  ClasslibraryService(Dependency1 dependency1, Dependency2 dependency2 = null)
{
    _dependency1 = dependency1;
    _dependency2 = dependency2 ?? new Dependency2(new Dependency3());
}
```

This introduces a default implementation for real code which can be overridden in unit tests. You can then revisit this code later and make it purer.